# PHP DateTime::createFromFormat() returns wrong year

Tags: php, datetime

I am trying to convert a datetime in a specific format to another format but for some reason the year is 4 years in the future

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:m:i.u\Z', '2015-08-30T07:56:28.000Z')->format('Y-m-d');
```

this echoes out `string(10) "2019-08-30"`

I have tried this and it outputs correctly

```
$date = new DateTime();
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

What could be causing the error with the year?

Comment: You're using "m" for your minutes value. That's actually months, hence you're adding 56 months (about 4 years) to your date. Try it with "i" for minutes. Also, I'm guessing you meant to use "s" for the seconds.

Comment: to expand on @MattGibson lower case m is for minute upper M is for month

Comment: Good spot.  Don't know how I missed that :)

Comment: @Andrei Nope, "m" and "M" are both for months.

Comment: @Andrei It is wrong // lower case m is for minute upper M is for month //

Comment: D: _why PHP why_ keep mixing my languages. ADyson appears to have the correct answer based on the docs

Comment: @Adam did the answer help? If so please remember to mark it as "accepted" - thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.u\Z', '2015-08-30T07:56:28.000Z')->format('Y-m-d');
```

`i` is used for minutes, and `s` for seconds. `m` is for months. Therefore your string is being interpreted incorrectly.

For the correct format characters to use, see http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php